# Incorrect syntax highlighting? "Variables made special by use in arguments" not working

Tags: syntax, variable, iterators, syntax-highlighting

This example is obviously not useful on its own, but it will cover everything I actually need to know for a more complicated function I'm making.

The example is to recreate the `Do` function, and call it `Do2`. My code is as follows:

```
Do2[function_, iterator_] := Do[function, Evaluate[iterator]]
SetAttributes[Do2, HoldAll]
```

This works correctly as expected, i.e. the functionality of `Do2` is exactly the same as the functionality of `Do` (I think). However, the syntax highlighting is clearly different for the two functions:
[image: Do2's iterator is blue, but Do's iterator is cyan]

Do2's iterator i is blue, but Do's iterator i is cyan.

Using the "Why the Coloring?" tool under Help, you can see that:
[image: the i of Do is under "Variables made special by use in arguments", but the i in my Do2 is under "Global symbols that have no value assigned".]

the `i` of `Do` is under "Variables made special by use in arguments",

but the `i` in my `Do2` is under "Global symbols that have no value assigned".

**How do I get the `i` of `Do2` to be under "Variables made special by use in arguments"?** It seems like it should be under this category, and that the highlighting is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE! (Note that I think you shouldn't be using `Evaluate` there: consider `i=3; Do2[Print[i], {i,5}]`.) Syntax highlighting is done in terms of the syntax *only*, and the front end's processing of that syntax; the downvalue of `Do2` (that is, the definition you gave it via `:=`) is not a syntactic property the front end can access.

But there *is* a way to achieve the syntax highlighting you want by informing Mathematica of the syntax information...

```
SyntaxInformation[Do2] = SyntaxInformation[Do]
```

Note, however, that your function is *not* quite like `Do`: `Do` can take multiple iterators, and will loop over all of them, whereas this definition only takes one iterator, in its 2nd argument. So (just as a way of illustrating it a bit further) the syntax information for your function should be:

```
SyntaxInformation[Do2] =
  {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _}, "LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2}}}
```

(See [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) for more details.) Note that this will set the syntax highlighting *regardless* of the functionality. So, for example,

```
(* Nonsense definition: *)
Do3[x_] := 2

SyntaxInformation[Do3] = SyntaxInformation[Do]
```

will still make the syntax highlighting of `Do3` like that of `Do`, even though it doesn't behave at all similarly.